# To show that $\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{\sin(t/2)}$ is bounded on $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Given that $f$ is Lipschitz, I am trying to show that $\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{\sin(t/2)}$ is bounded on [$-\pi,\pi$]. But I am not getting how I will bound the denominator. What I did is as follows:

$\left|\frac{f(x-t)-f(x)}{\sin(t/2)}\right| \leq C \left\rvert\frac{t}{\sin(t/2)} \right\rvert$. I saw the graph of function, it is clearly bounded but I am failing to give mathematical reason. Any hint.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done it almost completely, observe that now you only need to argue that $\frac{t}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}$ is bounded on $[-π,π]$, which is same as saying $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is bounded on $[-\frac{π}{2},\frac{π}{2}]$. Now, that is a continuous function on compact interval, hence bounded.

Comment: oh yes...i was worried about point 0 but we can extend it continuously at 0 by setting value 1.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Mean Value Theorem:
$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(\xi)(b-a)$$

Comment: should i continue like this...$C \mid \frac{ t}{sin(t/2)} \mid =2C  \mid \frac{ t/2 - 0 }{sin(t/2) - sin0} \mid = 2C \frac{1}{sin'(\xi)}$...but still it won't be bounded...

Comment: I would write $$f(x-t)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(x-t-x)$$ and $f'(\xi)$ must bounded

Comment: As stated above is $$\frac{t}{\sin(\frac{t}{2})}$$ is bounded on the given interval

Comment: got it..thanks.